# Make QWebsocket a QIODevice for QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

So I've found a `QtWebsockets` are a handy thing.
I'd like to use `QtWebsockets` as a `QIODevice` for use in `QDataStream`.

Unfortunately, initializing a `QDataStream` doesn't accept `QtWebsockets` as a `QIODevice`.
Something like this:

```
QDataStream & operator<<(QDataStream & stream, const ClientPayload & m)
{
   stream << (qint32)m.int_x << (qint32)m.int_y;
   return stream;
}

  QByteArray buf;
  QWebSocket m_socket;
  QDataStream bds(&buf, m_socket);
```

Would I have to subclass QWebsocket to make it adaptable to become QIO Device?